# Move Sort By and Per Page section in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-list, category-listing

How can I move these two sections in breadcrumbs?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Copy the below file to your theme:

**vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml**

and change:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
</block>
```

to:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs" before="-"/>
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
</block>
```

and then copy the below file to your theme:

**vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml**

and update the code with below:

```
<?php
/**
 * Product list toolbar
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
 */
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;
?>
<?php if ($block->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>
    <div class="toolbar toolbar-products" data-mage-init='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getWidgetOptionsJson() ?>'>
        <?= $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
        <?php if ($block->isExpanded()): ?>
            <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/viewmode.phtml')) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/amount.phtml')) ?>

        <?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>

        <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml')) ?>

        <?php if ($block->isExpanded()): ?>
            <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/sorter.phtml')) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Similarly, you can do for **Per Page** section.

Answer (score 0):

You can override template, then you may not need to add it in xml, just copy the breadcrumb.phtml file to your theme's directory and you can modify it in your theme.

You can put your breadcrumb.phtml file at below path.

```
app\design\frontend\<VENDOR_NAME>\<THEME_NAME>\Magento_Theme\templates\html\
```

Comment: yes, Already there